# Bash script using sed acts differently when passing variable

Tags: bash, sed

I have a script that I am writing that checks a value and then based on the value modifies it.

I am trying to understand why it works this one way and not the other. Based on the google and stackoverflow searches I did, nothing really fits what I am trying to understand.

The value it is trying to change is test_value = 5 and changes the 5 to a 6.  In the file there are two like lines.

```
test_value = 5
test_value_action = log
```

Script content is below:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    CHECK="test_value"
    sed -i 's|^\("$CHECK" = \).*|\1'6'|' /user/file.txt
```

That doesn't work.  But if I hard code the value for check it works

```
    #!/bin/bash
    CHECK="test_value"
    sed -i 's|^\(test_value = \).*|\1'6'|' /user/file.txt
```

What am I failing to understand?  Also for other ones I have wrote where there is only one single line in the file that it can match, it works with $CHECK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your variable is still within single quote hence not getting expanded. Use:

```
sed -i 's|^\('"$CHECK"' = \)*.|\1'6'|' /user/file.txt
```

Comment: so you want me to add the single quotes around the double quotes of $CHECK?

Comment: Be careful that the value in `$CHECK` doesn't have any sed pattern metacharacters if you use this sort of approach.

Comment: @roadzy Not quite, you are creating *three* quoted strings. `'s|^\('`, `"$CHECK"`, and `' = \)*.|\1'6'|'` (though technically that last one is two quoted strings and an unquoted `6`).

Comment: @roadzy You aren't putting them around the double quotes but rather separating the command into 3 sections `'s|^\('` `"$CHECK"` `' = \)*.|\1'6'|'` as the variable wont work inside the single quotes.

Comment: @etan reisner that's a good point about sed pattern metacharacters in the variable but I know exactly what it is going to be in it since I am setting it above.  Its just text.

Comment: @roadzy: In that case this answer should work for you.

Comment: Yes it does work.  It just won't let me accept the answer for another minute.